# Validate columns in a csv file are present in another csv file JAVA

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I have two arrays `ArrayList<String> csv1` and `ArrayList<String> csv2`

csv2 has more columns than csv1 but the goal is to check that all columns in csv1 are present in csv2, regardless of the extra files.

I esstenially want the code to only look at the columns in csv1 and check if they are in csv2 and nothing else.

Currently its giving me a 'false' output because there are extra columns in csv2 so its saying that they do not match.

I have a class called ReadCsvFile that reads csv files from a path

````
Public static void main(String[] args) {
ReadCsvFile readFile - new ReadCsvFile();
ArrayList<String> csv1 = (ArrayList<String>) readFile.readcsv1(some parameters here);
ArrayList<String> csv2 = (ArrayList<String>) readFile.readcsv2(some parameters here);
Collections.sort(csv1);
Collections.sort(csv2);
System.out.println(csv1.equals(csv2)); ```
````

Comment: Can you share more code : how do read the files and fill both lists ? Does the lists contains all the file (one String == one line) OR only the fields of the header ? Please clarify

Comment: I added some more code - hopefully it makes it more clear. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You want to know if csv2 containsAll of csv1?
Have you looked at the available Methods that Collection or List offers?

Comment: Ive tried ```containsAll``` but not working. I don't have much experience.

Answer (score 0):

The line `csv1.equals(csv2)` would mean that both file contents are strictly identical.

---

What you want is :

- check only header line : use `List.get(0)` and split on the good separator
- check if columns of 1 are all in 2 : use `List.containsAll`

```
// use your separator if not comma
List<String> header1 = Arrays.asList(csv1.get(0).split(","));
List<String> header2 = Arrays.asList(csv2.get(0).split(","));

boolean ok = header2.containsAll(header1);
System.out.println(ok);
```